# Ignite thread-safe variant of java.util.List

Tags: ignite

Not Sure If Ignite provides thread safe (concurrent) version of java.util.List, or is there any hack that should be done to achieve the same functionality that of concurrent List

Answer (score 0):

These are [distributed data structures](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/data-structures) that are supported by Apache Ignite at the moment. A distributed list is not among them. Probably you may use distributed queue or set for your use case.

Basically, you may store `java.util.List` as a cache entry updating the list and picking a particular element from it with `IgniteCache.invoke(...)` method. This `EntryProcessor` based approach will avoid a necessity to send the list over the wire every time you need to add a new element to it or take an existed one.